# Is there library to convert text, image to pdf In react-native?

Tags: react-native, pdf, lib

Is there any library to convert text, image to pdf document in react-native?
(Library like pdfbox in android studio)

I only found a library that converts html from app to pdf.
https://aboutreact.com/make-pdf-in-react-native-from-html-text/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library for Image: "react-native-image-to-pdf"

https://github.com/Anyline/react-native-image-to-pdf

Also you can add text to pdf using this library: "react-native-pdf-lib"

https://github.com/Hopding/react-native-pdf-lib